# How to enlarge the size of modal in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="modal  fade" id="_saleman">
<div class="modal-dialog " >
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#F5F5F5" >


       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> I have read many talks on this but i havn't found any 
>    good and easily working ans
>   If it get resized then it will not be resposive 
>   *Respond fast *

Comment: use `modal-lg` class in your `modal-dialog`

Comment: i donot want that size. i want to make comple registration fome in modal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="modal-dialog " >
 </div>
```

. use these classes
 **modal-lg    modal-sm  container  container fluid** 
   
like

```
 <div class="modal fade">

 <div class="container">
    </div>
 </div>
```

> *The modal will be enlarged and resposive to

Answer (score 0):

> Use "modal-lg" class for large modal
>
> you can visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ for
>   different size and properties of modal (Bootstrap 4). And visit
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals for for Bootstrap
>   3 . You can refer this document for all properties of Bootstrap Model